# file_get_contents json decode showing nothing

Tags: php, json, api, jsondecoder, jsonencoder

I m using google site verification recaptcha API for my website.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$response."&remoteip=".$ip);
```

when I print `echo $json;` its showing proper response

`{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2018-08-23T12:43:42Z", "hostname": "staging.my.com" }`

but when i tried

`$data = json_decode($json,true);`
 `echo $data->success;`

its showing nothing

Could anybody tell me what i am missing??

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2018-08-23T12:43:42Z", "hostname": "staging.my.com" }';
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

This produces an associative array from your example JSON string, not an object (used `var_dump($data);` to see what you actually have stored).
Just use the proper syntax for accessing array values:

```
echo $data["success"]; // prints '1'
```

or:

```
echo ($data["success"])?'success':'failure'; // prints 'success'
```

Comment: Well this new for me, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP doc if you set the second parameter `assoc` to true the function returns associative arrays instead of std class.

```
 mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = FALSE [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

> assoc
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So either try `$data['success']` or change `json_decode($json, true)` to `json_decode($json)`.